# How will I know whether the blocking library method executes in a thread they own or not?

Tags: java, multithreading

An abstract from JCIP -

> Tasks do not execute in threads they own; they borrow threads owned by
>   a service such as a thread pool.....
>
> This is why most blocking library methods simply throw
>   InterruptedException in response to an interrupt. They will never
>   execute in a thread they own,..

Consider the snippet in a thread:

```
void run(){
   try{
       blockingQueue.put(...);          // statement 1
   }catch(InterruptedException e){
       // exception handling....
   }
}
```

As `BlockingQueue.put()` is a blocking method, does that means **task (statement 1)** never executes in the above thread which it owns?

Answer (score 1):

> Tasks do not execute in threads they own

Means that a task DO NOT own a thread for **itself**, it only executes in a thread it borrows. That is, there is no way we can start a task without assigning a thread for it, because the task can not create a thread itself.

In your code, task (statement 1) execute in the thread (which run method locate in) you assign for it, task (statement 1) will not execute in a thread it own (create).